# Different results on random forest between R and Google Earth Engine

Tags: r, random-forest

I've implemented Random Forest regression algorithm in R (randomForest package) and GEE, but they are giving me very different results (average difference is 4% o and going up to 19% in some cases), and mainly the extreme values (low and high) differ very much.

I'm controlling for:
**number of trees
variables per split
seed
node size**. And this is all the common parameters between the two implementations, as far as I understand.

What else can I do to improve the agreement between the two? I did not found any useful documentation of the GEE implementation.

Comment: I was also going to suggest Max depth

Comment: Could you please share your code for Random Forest Regression in GEE? My email ID is ramkumardeo@gmail.com I'm also trying to implement Random Forest Regression in GEE to map aboveground biomass. Thanks in advance for your help. Ram

Answer (score 1):

A couple things could be going on. Based on the nature of the algorithm the seed may not control the randomization. Also, GEE and R have a different default for the bag fraction, or how much data is withheld when growing the forest. I believe GEE is set to 0.5 and R is like 0.63 or so. Additionally, GEE can be set to run in out-of-bag mode or not.